# How to parse mutipart form Data in Python

Tags: python, upload

I am using AWS API Gateway to upload mutiple files like csv , txt . There is one pyhon Lambda behind the gateway. I get the multi part response like below. I want to know how I can get the content of these files and upload to S3

```
----------------------------124218046032878137249340
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="2.csv"

Content-Type: text/csv

header,value

a,1
b,2

----------------------------124218046032878137249340

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file2"; filename="1.txt"

Content-Type: text/plain

aa
bb
cc

----------------------------124218046032878137249340--
```

code:-

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    print(event)
    my_body = event['body-json']
    decoded_body = base64.b64decode(my_body)
    my_multipart = str(decoded_body, 'utf-8')
```

Comment: How are you running this lambda function? Where is the response coming from? You certainly shouldn't need to parse it. Show the code.

Comment: I am invoking the AWS api gateway URL from Postman . I selected two files to upload in postman . Then my Lambda is running in AWS  behind the AWS API gateway. when I see the "event" data in lambda , I get these contents. Now I want to get back the two file contents by parsing it and save into s3.  code is